# Добавить пользователю административных прав

Tags: linux, debian

Добавил нового пользователя как стандартного в linux, а старого удалил, у которого были права администратора,не подумал, и теперь новый пользователь ничего не может сделать. Добавить его в группу sudo я не могу, отредактировать /etc/sudoers тоже. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не можете редактировать файл sudoers и добавить нового пользователя в группу sudo, то у вас есть несколько вариантов:

- Используйте утилиту `su` для получения прав администратора и внесите изменения, которые нужны.
- Используйте утилиту pkexec для запуска команд с правами администратора: `pkexec 'command'`
- Если ни один из вышеперечисленных вариантов не работает, вы можете попробовать использовать загрузочный диск, чтобы перезагрузить систему в режиме восстановления и внести изменения в файл sudoers или добавить пользователя в группу sudo. Например, если вы используете дистрибутив Ubuntu, вы можете следовать инструкциям на странице "RecoveryMode" (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), чтобы войти в режим восстановления и внести изменения в систему.

Comment: спасибо, буду перезагружаться